# How to constrain random effect in lmer() to known value (to calculate Cohen's f2)

Tags: r, lme4

I am attempting to calculate Cohen's f2 as a measure of "local" effect size in a mixed-effects regression model (Selya et al., 2012, https://doi.org/10.3389/fpsyg.2012.00111 ), using lme4 in R.

The procedure involves comparing 3 models in order to calculate the reduction in residual variance that can be attributed to the fixed effect of interest (the 3 models are a "full" model with all predictors, a reduced model without the fixed effect of interest, and a "null" model with no fixed effects; for specifics, see Eqs. 2 and 3 in Selya et al., 2012).

Importantly, it is necessary to obtain the variance of random effects from the "full" model and hold this constant (the random effect variance) when fitting the reduced models.

Is there a way to achieve this in lmer(), i.e., to pre-specify the variance of a random effect so that it is a known value?

Comment: SO isn't really the place for question that combine coding and conceptual problems. I suggest you take this to https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-mixed-models

Comment: Thank you! I did indeed. Here, I deleted the 2nd part of the question, so that it is more specifically about lmer(). Is this acceptable? Thanks!

Comment: I've tried blmer(), but although it allows a specific value as a prior for residual variance with `resid.prior=point(x)`, this is not possible for the random effect variance (`cov.prior` cannot take `point()`).